# Powerpoint VBA to update links on excel files open by someone else without alerts

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation that links to multiple large excel spreasheets. I want to update the links so my presentation as a whole is updated. However, I if click in `Update All Link`, my powerpoint crashes, probably because the linked excel files are large. So I would have to update manually each link so it will not crash.

This macro below will loop each linked object and update its link, however, if the file is currently open, it will pop a alert if I want to cancel, open read only or notify. The display alerts set to false will do nothing against it.

```
Sub linkupdate()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim oshp As Shape
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        osld.Select
        For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
            If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                oshp.Select
                oshp.LinkFormat.Update
            End If
        Next oshp
    Next osld
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I have found that powerpoint opens an invisible excel aplication underneath it to update the links, however I could not grab this open instance with my vba and tell it to open the links readonly .

I want however for this do not happen if the file is open by someone else, but however I want it to automatically open the file for update as read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, **I am assuming all of this is being done from within the PowerPoint VBA editor**. With that being said, let me explain why you're getting the Pop-up from the Excel application. When you wrote this line of code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

**You're referring to the PowerPoint application, what you're meaning to do is to refer to the Excel application because I am assuming that the popup is happening there.** In order to fix this, we need to create a reference to the Excel application. If I add the following code **we can turn off the displays for the Excel application**:

```
'Declare Excel Variables
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

'Create a new Excel Application, make it invisible, set the Excel Display alerts to False.
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

So now that we've handled the pop-up let's fix your link issue. To fix the link issue, we are going **to open the Excel workbook that the link is referring to in the background**. This way updating the links goes faster. **If we don't open the workbook, I have had an instance where the update link process can easily take over 5 minutes.**

However, to get the correct file name can be a little challenging if the object is a linked chart for example. **We need to parse the file so that way it removes the worksheet name and the chart name.** Here is how we do that:

```
'Get the Source File of the shape.
 SourceFile = PPTShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

'We may need to parse the Source file because if it's linked to a chart, for example, we can get the following:
'C:\Users\NAME\ExcelBook.xlsx!Chart_One!
'We want it to look like the following:
'C:\Users\NAME\ExcelBook.xlsx

'This will parse the source file so that it only includes the file name.
Position = InStr(1, SourceFile, "!", vbTextCompare)
FileName = Left(SourceFile, Position - 1)
```

Next, we want to open the workbook, update the link, and then close the workbook. So we will add this section of code:

```
'This will open the file as read-only, and will not update the links in the Excel file.
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, False, True)

    'Update the link
    PPTShape.LinkFormat.Update

'Close the workbook and release it from memory.
xlWorkBook.Close
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
```

Altogether here is how your code will look in order to update the links of all the different linked OLEObjects.

```
Sub UpdateLink()

    'Declare PowerPoint Variables
    Dim PPTSlide As Slide
    Dim PPTShape As Shape

    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

    'Create a new Excel Application, make it invisible, set the Excel Display alerts to False.
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = False
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Loop through each slide in the Presentation.
    For Each PPTSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

        'Loop through Each Shape in the slide
        For Each PPTShape In PPTSlide.Shapes

            'If the Shape is a linked OLEObject.
            If PPTShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then

                'Get the Source File of the shape.
                SourceFile = PPTShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

                'We may need to parse the Source file because if it's linked to a chart, for example, we can get the following:
                'C:\Users\NAME\ExcelBook.xlsx!Chart_One!
                'We want it to look like the following:
                'C:\Users\NAME\ExcelBook.xlsx

                'This will parse the source file so that it only includes the file name.
                Position = InStr(1, SourceFile, "!", vbTextCompare)
                FileName = Left(SourceFile, Position - 1)

                'This will open the file as read-only, and will not update the links in the Excel file.
                Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, False, True)

                    'Update the link
                    PPTShape.LinkFormat.Update

                'Close the workbook and release it from memory.
                xlWorkBook.Close
                Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

            End If

        Next PPTShape
    Next PPTSlide

    'Close the Excel App & release it from memory
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also be careful when you paste objects into the PowerPoint slide, if you're using VBA to achieve this sometimes it can paste the link information incorrectly! When you go to update links nothing will change because the link is not correct and isn't actually referencing the item you want to update.

Comment: Please check your task manager and kill any Excel instances prior to running this VBA code.